# Is this question subjective and opinion?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wonder if I should not ask this question or ask it some other place, maybe UX?

I have a website for online classifieds similar to craigslist. Now I wonder which feature to launch next: Video uploads, video conversations, paypal integration, telephone functionality or just improve the basic functions. How can I evaluate which feature is best without actually launching it and doing the A/B testing?

Comment: Sounds like market research is required. Not quite sure what's the best place to ask that.

Comment: I am a retired business man and I would ask you which would be the easiest and cheapest to implement and give the greatest impact in functionality for your users. That is where you start. Other than that, your question would be off-topic on the Q&A side, but not in Chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters You are always welcome to ask anything you want there. Well... almost anything! ;-) It can take a while to get an answer, however, a question like this one would get answers quickly! Cheers!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's very subjective mate, and it'll be too broad if you post it here. 
You are wondering which feature to launch and how to evaluate that feature. Every feature is ok, but it all depends on requirements. So, you'll had a few opinion based answers.